Find lower bound in scatter plot
This queston is actually linked to a question I have posted 2 days ago. Jut for reference, this is the link to it:
Question Version 1
As there is aparently no answer to the way I was thinking about it, my thought is to filter the data.
So, I have this dataset:
    d = {'Point': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], 
 'Interval 1': [92.417, 117.364, 126.302, 121.816, 126.083, 85.267, 84.977, 85.610, 84.909, 84.535, 85.024, 85.059, 84.798, 84.001, 84.157, 104.918,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],
'Interval 2':['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',157.884,163.604,122.905,84.770,83.386,83.530,83.418,83.423,83.350,83.618,83.486,83.846,83.622,83.796,83.942,84.068,84.379,84.175,84.010,84.439,84.479,84.599,84.998,101.860]}

I convert the dataset to a dataframe:
data = pd.DataFrame(d)

The data is then filtered so that I only have the lowest 10% of values in Interval 1 and 2.
I look for the min value in both columns:
min_val = min(data['Interval 1'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').min(), data['Interval 2'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').min())

Then I need to convert the emty strings to NaN
cols = ['Interval 1', 'Interval 2']

data[cols] = data[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

The data is looking in an Excel graph like this:

What I am trying to do is to have a python code looking in the data and pick only the low values of both series. Something like looking at first value, then check if next value is higher -> if yes, store first value, if not, store second value temporarily and repeat the process for all data points.
Maybe there is some other option, I am open for all sugestions.
Thank you!

I'm trying to distill your question.
First, I don't know what you try to achieve with the min_val, you obtain it, then you never mention it again.
Second, the plot you show does not correspond to the data you provide. Clearly, Interval 1 has a "flat" part at height around 85.
Regardless I will try to answer your main question. To do this the "pandas" way, you should use shift. Let's focus on Interval 1. You can create a shifted column like this: data['Interval 1 shifted'] = data['Interval 1'].shift(-1) - this shifts the column by 1.
Then, you can filter by data['Interval 1'] by comparing it to its shifted column, just like the linked question:
data['lower points interval 1'] = data['Interval 1 next row'] > data['Interval 1']

This will create a column with True/Falses you can filter on.

Hello DWe1, thank you for your help.
The min value is used to eliminate all rows that are more then 10% larger then min_value.
Your solution is getting me into the right direction, but is only working with 1 step.

A friend of mine helped me with following solution:
def find_min_in_descending_trends(values):
    min_values = []
    descending_trend = []

    for i in range(1, len(values)):
        if values[i] < values[i-1]:
            descending_trend.append(values[i-1])
            descending_trend.append(values[i])
        else:
            if descending_trend:
                min_values.append(min(descending_trend))
                descending_trend = []

    if descending_trend:
        min_values.append(min(descending_trend))

    return min_values

Example for "call function"
values = [84.77, 83.386, 83.53, 83.418, 83.423, 83.35, 83.618, 83.486, 83.846, 83.622, 83.796, 83.942, 84.068, 84.379, 84.175, 84.01, 84.439, 84.479, 84.599, 84.998]
min_values = find_min_in_descending_trends(values)

print(min_values)

This is doing what I need with 1 issue:
If trend is negative, all OK, if trend positive, I need to get rid of the first value.
